# How to handle Javascript empty object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm stumped.

This is code:

```
const clientInfoPromise = buildPromiseMethod
clientInfoPromise.then((clients) => {
    console.log('clients ' + JSON.stringify(clients))
    console.log(clients.typeOf)
    console.log(_.keys(clients))
```

This is output:

```
clients {}
undefined
['undefined']
```

I would like _.keys(clients) to return an empty array instead of an array with the string 'undefined'. 
`_.isEmpty(clients) ? [] : _.keys(clients)` doesn't work, because `_.isEmpty` returns `false`.

ClientInfoPromise is defined here:

```
static buildPromiseMethod(cids) {
    if (condition) {
        // fetch data
        const data = [data,data1,data2]
        return Promise.resolve(_.zipObject(cids, data));
    } else {
      const clients = _(cids)
        .indexBy()
        .mapValues(() => {
          return undefined; //contains empty data
        })
        .value();
      return Promise.resolve(clients);
    }
  }
```

`cids` can be `undefined`, `[]`, or `[1,2,3]` (array of numbers).

Comment: Looks like you are missing the closing curly brace and parens at the end of your first code block.

Comment: hmm? `_.keys(undefined).length === 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> console.log(clients.typeOf)

To log the type of `clients` use `console.log(typeof clients)`.

> console.log(_.keys(clients))
>   < ['undefined']

`_.key` is reporting that `clients` has a single key, which is named `"undefined"`. Most likely, this key-value pair is not being shown by `stringify` because its value is also undefined, which means it will be skipped by `stringify`.

To verify this, instead of

> console.log('clients ' + JSON.stringify(clients))

use

```
console.log('clients', clients)
```

This will show you **all** the properties, including ones that `stringify` would skip because their value is undefined.

In your particular case, the behavior you report is best explained by a bug in `buildPromiseMethod`, namely that the promise it returns is being resolved to an object with a single key of "undefined` with an unserializable value. For instance, consider the following:

```
> clients = { undefined: undefined };
> console.log('clients ' + JSON.stringify(clients))
< clients {}

> console.log(_.keys(clients))
< ['undefined']
```

which is exactly what you are getting.

However, it is not obvious how `buildPromiseMethod` could be returning such a malformed object. The most likely culprit is `zipObject`. Is that really the exact source code you are running? For instance, `_.zipObject([cids], data)` (specifying `cids` as an array, when its value is undefined, while `data` also contains undefined values) could result in the reported behavior:

```
var data, data1, data2;       // values are undefined
data = [data, data1, data2];
var cids = undefined;
_.zipObject([cids], data);

> { undefined: undefined }
```

By the way, it's likely that your use of promises is wrong, at least assuming that `// fetch data` is asynchronous. You probably want

```
static buildPromiseMethod(cids) {
  if (condition) {
    return fetchdata().then(data => 
      _.zipObject(cids, data));
  }
```

or something similar. This could be connected to your problem, if `data1` etc. is coming back from the promise, and you are trying to access it before the promise completes in which case its value will be undefined.